# How to remap tab shortcut from ctrl to alt for Chrome in Windows?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I use Ubuntu & Windows regularly. In Ubuntu, you can switch tabs by using either "`ctrl` + `[num]`" or "`alt` + `[num]`" but in Windows, you can only switch with `ctrl`.

I can't seem to find anything about this topic in a Windows environment. **Is there anyway I can get this behavior in Windows?** It's much more convenient to use `alt` and I use this shortcut religiously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a chrome extension, [Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcut-manager/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf) that allowed me to create new shortcuts to re-map the tab shortcuts (and it can do a lot more).

[image: Screenshot of Extension Settings]

Comment: this solution no longer work, do you have other solution?

Comment: I don't, unfortunately. I've been using Mac for the last couple of years, so I haven't tried anything other than this extension.

Answer (score 0):

**[Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script**

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force

SetTitleMatchMode, 2

#IfWinActive ahk_exe chrome.exe | ahk_exe msedge.exe

!1::Send, ^1
!2::Send, ^2
!3::Send, ^3
!4::Send, ^4
!5::Send, ^5
!6::Send, ^6
!7::Send, ^7
!8::Send, ^8
!9::Send, ^9

#IfWinActive
```